# Is there a faster way to wrap and unwrap ImmutableJS objects?

Tags: redux, immutable.js

I have a fairly large data structure (array of hundreds of largish objects). I have to convert them into Immutable objects for use with my Redux store, and then convert them back for use with other components.

Using Immutable.fromJS takes a fair bit of time (hundreds to thousands of milliseconds). I only need the wrapper to be "thin", and I promise not to do anything sneaky behind Immutable's back. The main thing that will be done to them is to concatenate lists.

Does somebody have an alternative implementation of List that cheaply wraps the underlying array, without recursing all the way down? Or at least wrapping the data objects so that I don't have to convert all the way down?

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be to use the `List` constructor or `Immutable.List`, instead of `Immutable.fromJS`. It only wraps the list at the highest level.